# jquery click not adding class

Tags: jquery, css, click

trying to a simple nav menu and I know this is simple but why is the click not adding the class?  the append is there just for testing and works fine.

```
$('.menu').on('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass('hovering');
        $(this).append('hello');
});
```

see fiddle:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXfN8/)

Comment: as i can see class is added, but, since you have removeClass() on hover bellow, (on hover out) - it removes class? http://jsfiddle.net/aXfN8/2/

Comment: i knew it was something stupid.  thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you already have that class being applyed by the hovering.

You could specify a different class with !important for that as follows...

JQuery

```
$('.menu').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('hovering2');
    $(this).append('hello');
});
```

CSS

```
.hovering2{
    border:#000 1px solid;
    background:#333 !important;
}
```

[link to fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/aXfN8/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) on [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2) event

```
$(".menu").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hovering');
});
```

**Please not that the above can be accomplished via css**

```
.menu:hover {
    background:#737373;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class is added, but that has no effect as the other code has already added it when you hover it, and it will also remove it when you leave the element.

Use a different class for the click event.

CSS:

```
.selected {
    background:#737373;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.menu').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Rearrange the CSS rules so that you have the `.menu` class first, then the other will take precedence when you add them. For rules with the same specificity, the one specified after takes precedence.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/aXfN8/5/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery hover is really a listener for two events, mouseenter and mouseleave, http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Your code is working, however, the mouseleave event (second function in .hover) is being fired AFTER you click, which removes your '.hovering' class.

In this use-case, CSS pseudo selectors would also achieve what you are attempting in your hover states.